# High resolution image

Tags: html, css, image

My logo image has a high resolution but when I put it in the html code, the image is fuzzy and I didn't put any height or width I just put the image. I want that when I put my image on the website, the image remains in high resolution.

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header-wp">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <a class="cmn-toggle-switch cmn-toggle-switch__htx" href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar"><span>Menu mobile</span></a>
                        <div id="logo_home">
                            <h1><img style="margin-bottom: 10px;" src="img/logo.png" alt=""></h1>
                        </div>
                        <!--/top_nav-->
                    </div>
                    <!--/navbar-header-->
                </div>
                <!--/navbar-header-wp-->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="navbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a style="color: #cc9933;" href="index.html">Início</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- /Nav -->
    </header><!-- /Header --> ´´´
```

Comment: Depending on how you want the image to respond to different viewport sizes. One way you can help to keep the image quality is to use the CSS `object-fit: contain`

Comment: Take it out of your H1. You dont want to put an image inside a heading

Answer (score 0):

Learn about CSS `Object-fit` property here:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp, this will help stop or control how your image is scaled/displayed

Answer (score 0):

You want the rendered size of the image to be exact division by integer of original image size in pixels.

So if in your CSS `width: 140px` then use an image with actual width of `140px` or `280px` or `420px` etc.